# How to create multiple custom themes in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to create multiple custom themes in magento 1.5.1. Already I have mytheme folder in 
`app/design/frontend/base/mytheme`
and skin folder in 
`skin/frontend/base/mytheme/`

Now I want to create another custom theme which I have placed under
`app/deisgn/frontend/default/newtheme/template` &
 `app/deisgn/frontend/default/newtheme/layout`

but the problem is `newtheme` is not able to access media folder which has my images stuff.

Answer (score 0):

by 'media' folder are you referring to the media folder in Magento root directory or a folder such as 'images' in your skin folder?

You should not have any problem accessing no matter how you set up your theme structure.

If you are referring to some folder in your 'skin/frontend/base/mytheme/' folder, that's because your new theme will fall back to 'default/default' then 'base/default' and it will not get to your original folder. It is really not a good idea how you set up your theme structure but a quick solution for your problem will be creating a new skin folder for you new theme and copy whatever images across from the old skin folder.

Hope that helps.

Tony